# QML SectionScroller and QList<QObject*>

Tags: qt, listview, scroll, qml, qlist

I use `QList<QObject*>` as a model in my app. As there might be a lot of elements, I decided to use SectionScroller. When I try to scroll using the SectionScroller I'm getting a

`Error: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString`

What am I doing wrong?

My ListView is:

```
ListView
{
    id: irrview
    width: parent.width
    model: irregulars.db // QList<QObject*>
    anchors.top: caption.bottom
    anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
    clip: true
    section.criteria: ViewSection.FirstCharacter
    section.property: "form0"
    section.delegate: Item {height: 10; width: parent.width; Text { text: section } } // for testing purposes
    delegate: Rectangle
    {
        /**/
    }
}
```

Thanks

EDIT: more code:

the `irregulars` header

```
class IrregularListWrapper : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject*> db READ getdb NOTIFY langChanged)
    Q_ENUMS(Language)
public:
    enum Language
    {
        English = 0,
        German = 1
    };

    IrregularListWrapper() : db(0) { setLang(German); }
    ~IrregularListWrapper() { delete db; }
    QList<QObject*> getdb() const { return *db; }

    Q_INVOKABLE void changeLang(Language l) { delete db; setLang(l); }


signals:
    void langChanged();
protected:
    void setLang(Language);
    QList<QObject*> * db;
};
```

and the body of a function

```
void IrregularListWrapper::setLang(Language l)
{
    switch (l)
    {
    case English:
        db = new english;
        langName = "English";
        break;
    case German:
        db = new german;
        langName = "German";
        break;
    }
    emit langChanged();
}
```

the classes german, english are like that

```
class german : public QList<QObject*>
{
public:
    german();
};

german::german()
{
    append(new IrregularVerb("anfangen", "fing an", "angefangen"));
    /*more like that*/
}
```

and IrregularVerb:

```
class IrregularVerb : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString form0 READ getForm0 NOTIFY formChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString form1 READ getForm1 NOTIFY formChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString form2 READ getForm2 NOTIFY formChanged)
public:
    QString forms[3];
    QString getForm0() const { return getForm(0); }
    QString getForm1() const { return getForm(1); }
    QString getForm2() const { return getForm(2); }
    IrregularVerb(QString a, QString b, QString c) { forms[0] = a; forms[1] = b; forms[2] = c; }
protected:
    const QString& getForm(const int& ind) const { return forms[ind]; }
signals:
    void formChanged();

};
```

Edit 2: this doesn't work
If I do

```
QVariantList getdb() const { return QVariant::fromValue(*db); }

IrregularListWrapper.h:24: error: could not convert 'QVariant::fromValue(const T&) [with T = QList<QObject*>; QVariant = QVariant]()' from 'QVariant' to 'QVariantList {aka QList<QVariant>}'
```

If I remove the star, the error is similar.

EDIT3:

I found out this http://ruedigergad.com/2011/08/22/qml-sectionscroller-vs-qabstractlistmodel/

And found out that `irregulars.db.get` is undefined

And changed german and english to

```
class german : public AbstractIrregularList
```

and

```
class AbstractIrregularList : public QObject, public QList<QObject*>
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Q_INVOKABLE QObject* get(int index) {return at(index);}
};
```

But even now, irregulars.db.get(0) gives error (Result of expression 'irregulars.db.get' [undefined] is not a function.)

Why is happening like that, that the Q_INVOKABLE is not detected? The Q_OBJECT macro is there

/edit5: Even when using QVariant the errors are still there. It can be either treated as QList or as QObject*.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, you should use QVariantList instead QList<SomeClass> to expose list of elements from C++ to QML.

It should solve problem.

---

[Supported types in QML](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qtbinding.html#supported-data-types)

---

Try making code to look like this (in **irregulars** header):

```
Q_PROPERTY(QVariantList db READ getdb NOTIFY langChanged)
//...
QVariantList getdb() const {/*convert db to QVariantList*/ return converted_db;}
```

Or if you want to code look like from links you gave:

```
Q_PROPERTY(QVariantList db READ getdb NOTIFY langChanged)
//...
QVariant getdb() const {return QVariant::fromValue(db);}
```

Comment: AFAIK, QList<QObject*> can be used http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/qdeclarativemodels.html#qobjectlist-based-model - I even used it in another app

Comment: Take look at code, it is converted "QVariant::fromValue(dataList)" in order to be exposed, also link in my post shows you supported types in QML, and QList is not listed.

Comment: It's weird, as the QList<QObject*> contents are displayed ok. It's only SectionScroller that doesn't work. Code added
EDIT: It's even in the examples: http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/declarative-modelviews-objectlistmodel-main-cpp.html

Comment: I suspect it's because ctxt->setContextProperty takes QVariant as an argument. I'll try it out nevertheless

Comment: Wait, maybe I have found problem. Will update post. (but I am still curious how QList works for you in QML)

Comment: Its not the problem, I bet. This is only a label which indicates a section is started and this is displayed ok...
Maybe I have found the problem, I'll update tomorrow CET

Comment: I have no other idea except that QList is not recognizable to QML. Since you are extending QList in your AbstractIrregularList class, can you access methods like "at()"?

Comment: Also, I just realized that you have defined function like this: QVariantList getdb() const { return QVariant::fromValue(*db); }, but it should be like this: QVariant getdb() const { return QVariant::fromValue(*db); }. You can't assign QVariant to QVariantList.

Comment: But, that datatype is detected and its contents are shown.  The only problem is about. SectionScroller. I found in the code of SectionScroller that there is a call list.model.get... This method could be added via QAbstractListModel but I'd treat it as an overkill. I'll try QVariant, maybe it'll work!
Btw. iF you don't believ qlist qobject* can be used, why don' you try it out? :) I'm using Qt 4.7

Comment: Sorry, at the moment, I have only Qt5... However about 6 months ago I was making application for Nokia N9, and if I remember good, I had problems with QMap and QList (couldn't be exposed to QML) so I had to convert them to QVariantList.